# Monitoring on CloudFoundry instance and pull metrics like CPU usage and Memory utilization

Tags: performance, cloud, monitoring, performance-testing, cloud-foundry

As a part of performance Testing on cloud Foundry applications, i am now focusing more on server side (i.e containers where applications are stored) and interested in pulling out metrics which are useful to find bottlenecks such as
1) CPU consumption, 
2) disk usage, 
3) memory usage
4) Logs
Searched around internet but instead got a lot of confusions.Anyone can please suggest framework or tool that can be used to achieve the same using a windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to get metrics & logs would be through the firehose.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/loggregator/architecture.html#firehose

You use a Nozzle to get the information from the firehose.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/loggregator/architecture.html#nozzles

If you just want to experiment and see what information is available, you can use the firehose-plugin for the cf cli.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-plugin

Ideally, you'd end up finding or writing a nozzle to integrate with your metrics and log capturing platform.  For example, there is a DataDog nozzle for sending metrics off to DataDog.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/datadog-firehose-nozzle

There's also a nozzle for sending logs to a syslog server (like ELK).

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-to-syslog

And there's one for Splunk too.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/splunk-firehose-nozzle

Hope that helps!

Comment: What about this framework mozzle https://github.com/Bo0mer/mozzle which pulls metrics from CF and forwards it to 3rd party tools?